# QT - How to apply a QToolTip on a QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, tooltip

On a dialog I have a QLineEdit and a button. I want to enable a tool tip for the QLineEdit(in it or under it) when I press the button. Please give me a code snippet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
        Q_OBJECT

    public:

        MyWidget(QWidget* parent = 0) : QWidget(parent)
        {
            QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
            edit = new QLineEdit(this);
            layout->addWidget(edit);
            showButton = new QPushButton("Show tool tip", this);
            layout->addWidget(showButton);
            hideButton = new QPushButton("Hide tool tip", this);
            layout->addWidget(hideButton);

            connect(showButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(showToolTip()));
            connect(hideButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(hideToolTip()));
        }

    public slots:

        void showToolTip()
        {
            QToolTip::showText(edit->mapToGlobal(QPoint()), "A tool tip");
        }

        void hideToolTip()
        {
            QToolTip::hideText();
        }

    private:

        QLineEdit* edit;
        QPushButton* showButton;
        QPushButton* hideButton;
};
```

As you can see, there is no easy way to just enable the tool tip of some widget. You have to provide global coordinates to `QToolTip::showText`.

Another way to do this is to create a `QHelpEvent` yourself and post this event using `QCoreApplication::postEvent`. This way, you can specify the text to be shown in your widget using `QWidget::setToolTip`. You still have to provide global coordinates, though.

I am really interested in why you want to do this since tool tips are intended to be shown only when you hover your mouse *or* when you ask for the "What's this" information. It looks like bad design to use it for something else. If you want to give a message to the user, why don't you use `QMessageBox`?

Comment: Thanks. I want to use this in order to tell user that the QLineEdit is going to be filled with CapsLock ON state (for password field).

There are two questions: 1) Why if I don't separate this class definition in .cpp and .h files it gives linker error (some vtable problem)? And how I can have more then one QToolTips separately invoked in one class? I see you have used static functions you used.

Comment: 1: Probably because you didn't `#include` the moc file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001615/qt-moc-with-implementations-inside-of-header-files/ 2: I don't really understand your question. Do you mean show more than one tool tip at once? This is impossible.

Answer (score 5):

If you need tooltip for QLineEdit, so what is the problem? Just set:

```
myLineEdit->setToolTip("Here is my tool tip");
```

But if you need just to show some text after some `button` was pressed, here the another solution: create a slot, for example `on_myBytton_clicked()` and connect it to your button. In slot do the **setText()** function with your text on `QLabel`, `QTextEdit` and etc widgets located on your form.

Hope it help.

Comment: This is not what the OP asked. But you're right: I also think its a better idea to use a `QLabel` instead of a tool tip.

Comment: Your answer does not have any connection to my question. I ask how to use toolTip!!!

Comment: Seems you misunderstood. Does this code enable myLineEdit->setToolTip("Here is my tool tip"); a tooltip when I press the button???